# Python Looping Through A Directory Using a Regex Printing Only The Desired Results

Tags: python, regex

Being new to python, I have two files populated as such in a directory called test-caca in which I would like to loop through each of these files, searching for an ip address using a regular express and print out only the line and file that contains the desired data:

```
cat file9
192.168.3.11
192.168.1.1
10.255.3.1
10.7.0.145

cat file8
192.168.3.1
192.168.3.2
192.168.1.1
10.255.3.1
```

So far I have this:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
     for file in files:
       regexp = re.findall(r"10.7.0.145", open(file, "r").read())
       print " I found what I was looking for %s = %s" % (file,regexp)
 ....:         
I found what I was looking for file3 = []
I found what I was looking for file6 = []
I found what I was looking for file7 = []
I found what I was looking for file1 = []
I found what I was looking for file9 = ['10.7.0.145']
I found what I was looking for file5 = []
I found what I was looking for file8 = [] 
I found what I was looking for file10 = []   
I found what I was looking for file2 = []
I found what I was looking for file4 = []
```

How can I print just the line that contains what the regular expression found(ip address) like:

```
I found what I was looking for file9 = 10.7.0.145
```

and without the brackets ?

Comment: regexp is a list, you only want to print the contents instead of the whole list. That's where the brackets are coming from.

Comment: I'm confused why do you want to print the line with the IP address when you are passing in the IP address. Is there more info on the line with the IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.findall` returns a list.  Furthermore, empty lists evaluate to `False` in Python.  So, you can simply do this:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
       matches = re.findall(r"10.7.0.145", open(file).read())
       if matches:
           print " I found what I was looking for %s = %s" % (file,matches[0])
```

With the if-statement in place, the `print` line will only be run if `matches` is non-empty.

Also, in case you don't know, `[0]` gets the first (and only) item in `matches`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to rename `regexp` to what it actually is: A list of `matches`. That's one major point where the OP got confused.

Comment: Many thank yous for the responses. I tried that and it returns this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user3010612 - Really?  Is it on the line with `matches[0]`?  Because, if so, I don't see how.  `re.findall` returns a list and empty lists evaluate to `False`.  So, when it gets here: `matches[0]`, `matches` _must_ have an item.  Is the code copied correctly?  Remember that indentation is important.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you want is:

- Search all files below the current working directory for the string `10.7.0.145`
- If a match is found, print the name of the file that matched, and then print the first line that a match was found

If that's what you want, there's no need to mess around with regular expressions, a simple `if foo in data` will do:

```
import os

IP = '10.7.0.145'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for fn in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fn)
        with open (path, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if IP in line:
                    print "Match in file '%s':" % fn
                    print line
                    break
```

Comment: There are two things you can do to make this even better. 1) use this: `with open(path) as f:` and 2) remove `continue`.

Comment: Different, not necessarily better. 1) `'r'` may be the default mode, but I tend to specify it to make it clear at a glance that file is only ever used for reading. 2) He said `just the line`, which implies there's only ever gonna be one match. Checking the remaining lines would therefore be a waste of resources.

Comment: The first I will give you (although I think it is a waste of characters...but that is just a difference of style).  The second one though does nothing but jump to the top of the `for line in f:` loop again.  Why do this if falling off the for-loop does the same thing?

Comment: Err, you're totally right on the `continue` - I obviously meant to `break` (out of the line search) and "continue" with the next file.